# Convert a string of integers to byte array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, integer, byte

I have a string of integer "72101108108111" but it is a string representing bytes of original string "Hello".

How can I convert "72101108108111" to Ascii string "Hello" in Ruby?

Comment: You can't. There's no way to tell whether the first byte is `7` or `72`. If we guess `72` correctly there's no way to tell if the second byte is `1`, `10`, or `101`, and so on. However this string was generated, it wasn't generated with decoding in mind.

Comment: Can we do it if we assume 2 digits make a byte? i.e. its 72,10,11 etc?

Comment: That wouldn't give you "Hello." The ASCII code for `H` is 72, but `e` is 101.

Comment: I need to encode/decode a string to Base58. Found a gem which converts an integer to Base58. Trying to figure out if I can convert string to bytes and then encode and vice versa.

Comment: Concatenating the base 10 ASCII codes into a string of digits isn't the right way to "convert a string to bytes."

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question as clarified in comments (which has nothing to do with the title):

> I need to encode/decode a string to Base58

EDIT: now as a class (using base58 gem):

```
require 'base58'

class Base58ForStrings
  def self.encode(str)
    Base58.encode(str.bytes.inject { |a, b| a * 256 + b })
  end

  def self.decode(b58)
    b = []
    d = Base58.decode(b58)
    while (d > 0)
      d, m = d.divmod(256)
      b.unshift(m)
    end
    b.pack('C*').force_encoding('UTF-8')
  end
end

Base58ForStrings.encode('Hello こんにちは')
# => "5scGDXBpe3Vq7szFXzFcxHYovbD9c" 
Base58ForStrings.decode('5scGDXBpe3Vq7szFXzFcxHYovbD9c')
# => "Hello こんにちは"
```

Works for any UTF-8 string.

Comment: Thanks for help. And how do I get "Hello" from "9aJCVZR"? Decode will give me integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '72101108108111'
pattern=/^[a-zA-Z]/
index,res=0,''
while index<s.size
  len=0
  while (s[index..index+len].to_i.chr=~pattern).nil?
    len+=1
  end
  res << s[index..index+len].to_i.chr
  index+=len+1
end

p res
```

Try this , because the length of every string to be decoded is not certain.

For example, `"72->'H' , 101->'e' , 23->'\x17'"`

So every time we find the character decoded is not `"a~z" or "A~Z" (ex:\x17)`,

we just add the length and parse until we find character we want

For this case , the answer will be correctly `"Hello"`

It may malfunction on some case , but it works well now for my test

Just take it a look

> It only works without Exception on the case containing only "A-Z and a-z"

Comment: It's exclusive to the case only contains English character , remember it !